# I want to display the values in Table td based on IF condtions

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I want to print the values in table in such a way that.`<br>`
there are two `<td>` in the table. based on `<if>` condition `<td>` has to display the values.
And this should be in order, I mean no  should have blank values,like 
 
`(if i==1)` then 1st td will become blank and 2 td will get printed.
`(if i==2)` then 1st td will get display and 2 td will get blank.
Every  who has the value should get print one after the another without blank.

```
<table>
<%
   for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){ %>
     <tr> 
        <% if((i==2) || (i==4){  %>
            <td> only this 1st <td> get printed </td>    
        <%   } else {   %>
           <td> only this 2nd <td> get printed </td>
  <% }     
} 
 %>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve its unclear please elaborate

Comment: I am facing https://jsfiddle.net/ac1t8uL6/, but I want like this https://jsfiddle.net/njubckmg/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<%
   for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){ %>
     <tr> 
        <% if((i=2) || (i==4){  %>
            <td> only this 1st <td> get printed </td>    
        <%   } else {   %>
           <td> only this 2nd <td> get printed </td>
  <% }     
} 
 %>
```

Only your first `td` is getting printed because in your `IF` condition you are not comparing `$i` with value `2` instead you are assigning `$i=2` so change the `if(($i=2) || ($i==4))` to `if(($i==2) || ($i==4))` and will work good.

Hope this will help you in your problem